# Data warehouse for user data - design Q

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse

How to best store user data vs date/time dimension? Usecase is I am trying to store user actions per day, per hour. Such as number of Shares, likes, friends etc. I have a time table and a date table. For time it is easy - i have each row = user_id and colunms = 1 to 24 for each hour of the day. But problem is for dates. If i give each day = 1 colunm then i will have 365 colunms a year. I cannot archive the data way either because analytic needs past data too. What are the other strategies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
dimDate : 1 row per date
dimTime : 1 row per minute
```

At the beginning you have to state the "**grain**" of the fact table and then **stick to it**.

If the grain is one day, then `TimeKey` always points to the key of "23:59".

If the grain is one hour, then `TimeKey` points to entries of "HH:59".

If the grain is one minute, then `TimeKey` points to the respective "HH:MM"

If the grain is 15 minutes, then `TimeKey` points to the respective "HH:14", "HH:29", "HH:44", "HH:59"

And so on...

```
-- How many new friends did specific user gain
-- in first three months of years 2008, 2009 and 2010
-- between hours 3 and 5 in the morning
-- by day of week
-- not counting holidays ?

select
      DayOfWeek
    , sum(NewFriends) as FriendCount
from factUserAction as f
join dbo.dimUser    as u on u.UserKey = f.UserKey
join dbo.dimDate    as d on d.DateKey = f.DateKey
join dbo.dimTime    as t on t.TimeKey = f.TimeKey
where CalendarYear between 2008 and 2010
  and MonthNumberInYear between 1 and 3
  and t.Hour between 3 and 5
  and d.IsHoliday = 'no'
  and UserEmail = 'john_doe@gmail.com' 
group by DayOfWeek
order by DayOfWeek ;
```

Comment: Question: The userkey table - do i need a separate userID table for this in the DW or can i use the same user_id table where all the user info is stored? I assume user_id will be the same so i can use the same table correct?

Comment: @Rohit; there should be only one user table in the DW -- I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I guess the question is: The DW tables should it be separate from the business tables or use the same set of tables? Example: Say facebook. They have a user table, photo table, etc for the business needs of the site. Then they have their DW for the insight analytic. So is that a total separate of tables of using these business for their dimensions. Since my site is not big i am wondering if i can merge both (DW and business tables) together.

Comment: Also while modeling yesterday i had a question: The "dayOfWeek" etc... are these storing IDs or values? I can have a master date lookup table with all possible combination of dates as a PK and use that here as FK. Or i can store the values here like Jan = month 1, feb - month 2, etc.

Comment: @Rohit, values. Google "Kimball date dimension", here is one of these `http://arcanecode.com/2009/11/18/populating-a-kimball-date-dimension/`

Answer (score 1):

You would store the **date** in the dimension, and then add computed fields such as day_of_year.

On the designs I've worked on, we've never had more granular time slices than day, but I can't see why one couldn't have a time dimension based on date-hour, as the grain?

```
user_activity_facts(
   time_key references time_dimension(time_key)
  ,user_key references user_dimension(user_key)
  ,measure1
  ,measure2
  ,measure3
  ,primary key(time_key, user_key)
)
partition by range(time_key)(
   ...
)
```

Comment: Hm, that could work, i'll need to map it a bit. So assume i have 60 dimensions for 1:00pm to 2:pm, that means to output all activities between 1 and 2 pm i need to have 60 'where' in the query to capture each minute in?

Comment: Also this means if i need hour or minute by minute updates for each day then i will have 525,600 dimension rows per year? And i assume each year gets its own table correct?

Comment: I doubt you will get a noticable "compression" if you go sub hour. How many activities per hour does a user perform? Your terminology is a bit off. You have only one dimension. Each row represents a particular hour on a particular date. To output all activities between 18:00 and 20:00 last last friday, you would perform "xx between date '2011-02-04 18:00:00' and date '2011-02-04 20:00:00'"

Comment: Many if not most DBMSs support different types for DATE and TIME. Having separate attributes for date and time often makes sense. You can have a separate time dimension table as well as a date dimension so that you don't have to create all those extra rows in the date table.

Comment: yes, you're right. I'm spoiled by only having to work with day. With those numbers in mind, the only advantage I can see of combining day+hour in one table, would be better index selectivity from dimension -> fact, if you frequently query by both date and hour. But the size increase will most likely take away the advantage anyway :)